# Jquery $.ajax not fired on post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm using Jquery ajax to post data, but $.ajax is not fired. the click button is fired.

There's a javascript warning in firebug **Empty string passed to getElementById().**

Here's my code

```
$('body').on('click','button.btnsubmitads',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:base_url+"advertising/newads",
        dataType:"json",
        data:$("#newadsform").serialize(),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(result) {
            if(result.status){
                console.log('oke');
            } else {
                console.log('ga oke');
            }
        },
        error: function() {}
    });

    return false;
});
```

here's my form

```
<form class="newadsform form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="newadsform">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Listing</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select name="idlisting" class="span10" id="idlisting">

            <?php foreach($listing->result() as $data){
                echo "<option value=\"".$data->idlisting."\">".$data->title."</option>";
            }?>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Title</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span10" name="title" id="title">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <input type="hidden" id="inputimageadvs" name="imagename"  value="" />
        <input type="hidden" id="inputimagelarge" name="imagenamelarge"  value="" />
        <input type="hidden" id="inputimagethumb" name="imagenamethumb"  value="" />

        <label class="control-label">Image:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="example span10" style="margin:0;">
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    Please use PNG or JPEG extension only, and File size not more than 1 Mb (1024 Kb)
                </div>
                <ul id="uploadadv" class="styled"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions span10" style="margin:0;">
        <button class="btnsubmitads btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnsubmitads">
            <i class="icon-ok"></i> Submit
        </button>&nbsp;
        <button class="btn" type="reset" id="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: whether the form `newadsform` has elements with id as blank text.. can you share the form contents

Comment: @ArunPJohny okay, i'll ad to my question the form

Comment: also jquery and firefox versions

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm using Jquery.1.9.1 and firefox 24, post data also not working on Latest version of chrome

Comment: What does `$('button.btnsubmitads').length` and `$("#newadsform").length` return in the console? Should be greater than 0. Also, you should add some console output to your error func so it doesn't fail silently. Unrelated, using `return false;` is a bit of a misunderstanding of jQuery event handling, especially combined with `event.preventDefault()`. Good info on that here: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: The problem could be you are using content type `application/json`, where the request body should be json content, but you are sending request parameters instead

Comment: @JAAulde all length is 1

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm remove contentType: "application/json" .. It's still not working. are encoding type of my file is the problem? i'm using utf8

Comment: if you look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Fz9gz/2/ it is working

Comment: @user221915 ok, elements are found. Did you add any output to the error function yet?

Comment: @JAAulde I'm add xhr.status the results is 0, and xhr.responseText is undifined

Comment: @ArunPJohny yeah.. but why it's not work for me, or i must change the jquery version?

Comment: I used same version as yours 1.9.1

Comment: Also, it looks like you are trying to prevent the form from submitting and use manual ajax instead. This is fine. But if that's what you want, you should probably hook into the form submit action instead of the button click action. Specifically: `$('body').on('submit', '#newadsform', function (event) { ... })` instead of `$('body').on('click','button.btnsubmitads',function(event) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have Ads Block Installed.

Last day I've same problem.

try to change

```
url:base_url+"advertising/newads
```

with another word that not contain **ads** or **advertising** word